# Configure script fails: error: Canonical host info x86_64 unknown cygwin

Tags: cygwin, autoconf

If this is off-topic, please suggest where I might ask this question.

I'm recompiling a library on Cygwin using autotools.  I last built it four years ago, and at that time everything worked fine.

Now I have a new computer (actually, Win 7 on Paralles on OS X) and a fresh installation of Cygwin.  Autoreconf seems to work, but the configure script fails. Below are some snippets from the log file.  Some time spent with Google hasn't shed any light on this.  What is happening here?

---

```
hostname = gpajer-VBoxPC
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 2.8.0(0.309/5/3)
uname -s = CYGWIN_NT-6.1
uname -v = 2017-04-01 20:47

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = x86_64
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown
```

and

```
configure:2506: checking build system type
configure:2520: result: x86_64-unknown-cygwin
configure:2540: checking host system type
configure:2553: result: x86_64-unknown-cygwin
configure:2615: error: Canonical host info  x86_64 unknown cygwin
```

Comment: have you forced a `autoreconf -ifv` ?

Comment: Good comment, but yes I have, several times.

Comment: without seeing what is in configure before row 2615, difficult to say. I bet in the past you built on 32bit and the configure is fooled by the x86_64

Comment: Indeed, that is correct.  I'm slogging through the code to see why this might be the issue, but can you suggest where to look, or a fix?  Is it possible/likely that there is something in configure.ac that is defining a 32 bit system?  I'm quite an autotools novice.

Comment: Is the code available somewhere ?

Comment: I can make it available, or post snippets here.  What would be needed?  configure.ac?  I would have guessed that the 32/64 issue would be detected and dealt with.  I wonder if I'm missing a Cygwin package.

Comment: configure.ac and the *.m4 files are the usual suspects.

Comment: Here is configure.ac:  https://pastebin.com/AumHhVc2   This was written before my time.  The m4 files are autogenerated, no?  Here's aclocal.m4: https://pastebin.com/UTiPYAwP  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I notice an AC_MSG_ERROR() call.  I commented that out, and everything builds ok.  I have no clue why that's there, and how this built earlier.  I think the problem is solved, but if you have any ideas about that ERROR call, I'd appreciate hearing them.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code of configure.ac

```
     case "$host_os" in
            *darwin*)
                host_is_mac=yes
                AC_DEFINE([ML_OS_MACOSX], [], [Mac OS X])
                LFLAGS="${LFLAGS} -framework Accelerate"
                CXXFLAGS="-falign-loops=16 ${CXXFLAGS}"
            ;;
            *linux*)
                AC_DEFINE([ML_OS_LINUX], [], [Linux OS])
            ;;
            cygwin)
                AC_DEFINE([ML_OS_LINUX], [], [Linux OS])
                AC_DEFINE([ML_OS_CYGWIN], [], [Cygwin OS])
                AC_DEFINE([ML_OS_UNIX], [], [Unix OS])
        ;;
            *)
            ;;

esac

AC_MSG_ERROR([Canonical host info  $host_cpu $host_vendor $host_os])
```

I would expect to see additional asterisks

```
  *cygwin*)
```

as the two cases are, usually :

```
i686-pc-cygwin
x86_64-unknown-cygwin
```

Comment: I thought of that, too, and had tried it earlier today.  Same result.  Unless I didn't do it properly.  But that ERROR macro will stop processing unconditionally, won't it?  See my recent comment to my question. (forgot to address that to you)

Comment: Remember after editing configure.ac you need to regenerate configure.